# What is the scope of BPL dependencies

Tags: c++, delphi, package, c++builder, bpl

I got three BPL : A, B and C. A includes B and B includes C. They are all compiled and working correctly.

If I do some changes on C (add/delete attributes and methods) Should I recompile :

- C, B then A
- or just C then B

to make it works correctly?

In other words, when I do some changes on C, I have to compile B again because the enter points on C has changed. But do I have to compile also A again due to the last compile of B?

I would say that compiling C then B is enough but I am really not sure.

Comment: Depends. If the changes in C propagate to changes in method signatures of B then you need to rebuild C, B and A. It's probably the best to do so anyway.